# The "Do as I command" shard

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

I'm trying to get all the object shards at the moment (quite some work)
Now on the "living things" list there is one that's called "Do as I command"
I've read in several places that you're supposed to put a general next to a private. I've done this about thirty times and nothing happens...
Am I missing something? Do I have to give them special attributes or something?

Comment: Maybe create the general first and then the private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did to solve that one was:
1. Summon "Private"
2. Summon "**Bossy** General"

If it doesn't work try changing the area.

Comment: still nothing:S but thanks anyway

Comment: Then your game must be either buged or you're doing something wrong. Did you try doing that in another area? If it doesn't work in town go to another area and try there. You've got to summon both of them and place them close to each other and they should start to communicate with each other soon after that.

Comment: ah... finally. I never tried changing the area, wonder why. It worked on the farm:) thanks for the help!